# ImportError: No module named date

Tags: python, datetime

I can import datetime and access datetime.date but when I try to import datetime.date directly I get an import error. Why is this?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.date
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> import datetime.date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named date
>>>
```

https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/datetime/datetime.py

There seems to be a date class in datetime.py and today under that

To make matters more confusing there is datetime.date.today and datetime.datetime.now
https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/523fb72b80ff3325c6000732

Comment: `datetime.date` isn't a module. That syntax requires you to specify a module.

Comment: To make matters  more confusing there is datetime.date.today and datetime.datetime.now

Comment: (Also, the svn repo is really old. Old enough that development has migrated off of that, and then migrated off of the repo they migrated to.)

Comment: I could not find the file on the system I am working on for datetime so I just searched Google and that was one of the first results.

Comment: Not sure how much has changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> now = date.today
>>> now().month
8
```

You can use a variable to use the function directly

Answer (score 2):

**datetime** is module **Import** imports only the package.

To import the class, you can import it **from datetime import date**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import datetime.date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'datetime.date'; 'datetime' is not a package
>>> from datetime import date
>>> print (date)
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below syntax : `from`

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> print date
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: What about from datetime.date import today ? How can I just import the method today?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

- datetime.date.today() with import datetime
- date.today() with from datetime import date

Comment: What about from datetime.date import today  ? How can I just import the method today?

Comment: @UbuntuForums_Staff_Are_Trolls today is constructor method of date class. I don't think it is allowed to import a method of a class alone.